# Value error where a 1D array was expected but got an array with shape (18632, 3)

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I am currently learning segmentation and was using this project https://github.com/jalajthanaki/Customer_segmentation I found to learn but I reached the 99th cell and got a:
[image]

Here is the cell that is causing the problem:

```
# sum of purchases / user & order
temp = df_cleaned.groupby(by=['CustomerID', 'InvoiceNo'], as_index=False) 
['TotalPrice'].sum()
basket_price = temp.rename(columns = {'TotalPrice':'Basket Price'})

# percentage of the price of the order / product category
for i in range(5):
col = 'categ_{}'.format(i) 
temp = df_cleaned.groupby(by=['CustomerID', 'InvoiceNo'], as_index=False)[col].sum()
basket_price.loc[:, col] = temp 

# date of the order

df_cleaned['InvoiceDate_int'] = df_cleaned['InvoiceDate'].astype('int64')
temp = df_cleaned.groupby(by=['CustomerID', 'InvoiceNo'], as_index=False) 
['InvoiceDate_int'].mean()
df_cleaned.drop('InvoiceDate_int', axis = 1, inplace = True)
basket_price.loc[:, 'InvoiceDate'] = pd.to_datetime(temp['InvoiceDate_int'])

# selection of significant entries:
basket_price = basket_price[basket_price['Basket Price'] > 0]
basket_price.sort_values('CustomerID', ascending = True)[:5]
```

The reason this confuses me is I am not sure what array is causing this problem and google has not helped me. I am absolutely new to this so any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Post the exception as a formatted code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
for i in range(5):
col = 'categ_{}'.format(i) 
temp = df_cleaned.groupby(by=['CustomerID', 'InvoiceNo'], as_index=False)[col].sum()
basket_price.loc[:, col] = temp
```

Here **temp** supposed to be a **three** column dataframe & here

```
basket_price.loc[:, col] = temp
```

You are assigning a **three column dataframe** to a column, which doesnt make sense.

Comment: Please don't post python code as JavaScript snippets

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, I was trying how to choose python as language in code window but coudn't able to find it. Please do share best way to add python code.

Comment: Just a code block is fine. It won't be runnable in a browser.

Comment: I edited out the snippet stuff without changing anything else, now it's up to you to edit the indentation to make it valid python code.

Comment: So what should I do to fix it as it is not my code but a project done by someone else @Abhishek

Comment: @AnshulRaj you have to see which column need to be added to from "temp" dataframe to basket_price.loc[:, col] = temp[' choose_column'] based on your code requirement.

Comment: what would be the [' choose_column'] part in your opinion for this code? Cause I am just learning and have no idea how it should work but as the code goes it is adding the total value of a particular category and storing it as the basket price

Comment: Based on understanding it should be temp[col], but not sure how it will play in all code synergy.

Comment: Thank you but I figured it out

Comment: Please share how you solved it.